# Get name of dynamic div that is clicked in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a set of generated divs with a class called "class1". I need to be able to assign them a name or ID and then use JQuery to register that I have clicked on a particular one of those divs. I have this code but this doesn't work as all I know how to do is select the class name:

```
jQuery(".class1").click(function () {
     // do something                    
});
```

I need to be able to take the unique identifier of that clicked div and use it for something

Comment: Do you even *need* the name? Within the snippet you have provided you can just use `$(this)` to reference the clicked element. A couple of additional points to note - in jQuery 1.8+ (I believe) you should use `$(".class1").on("click", fn);`, or something similar (this is all documented on the jQuery website). Additionally I'd recommend against `class1`; use something which explains what it is used for - something which would help with future development if there is a vague possibility that others are going to be working on it in the future.

Comment: No I plan to change that useless class name haha. I do need the name or some kind of identifier because of the unique properties of each div. I just assigned each div in the class an id, and now but works!

Comment: Ok, but in the function `$(this)` *does* refer to the individual div. The properties will be the same whether you refer to it by `$(this)` or by id / name. Of course if you're then calling another function (which you made) and this requires the id for a call to `getElementById`, then it may be a different matter. However if this is the case then you can just pass in a jQuery object and loop over that using `elems.each(...` or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the id of the clicked element you can access the `id` property of `this` which has the context of the clicked HTML element.

```
jQuery(".class1").click(function () {
     // do something                    
     var theId = this.id; // contains the id of the clicked element, assuming is has an id.
});
```

You mention dynamic elements, in that case you need to either bind the event after the element has been added or bind with delegation.

For jQuery 1.7 and later use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
jQuery("body").on("click", ".class1", function () {
     // do something                    
     var theId = this.id;
});
```

For jQuery 1.6 and earlier use, [**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
jQuery("body").delegate(".class1", "click", function () {
     // do something                    
     this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're generation class name after DOM load.. dynamically then you need to use delegate event hander.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.class1', function() {

  // to assign name
  $(this).attr('name', 'someName');

  // to assign ID
  $(this).attr('id', 'someUniqueID');

  // to get

  this.id  //  to get id

  this.name // to get name

});
```

**NOTE:**

In case of delegate event handling, you should use any static-container element to `.class1` instead of `body`. That is efficient and best way.